# Avoid the creation of sublist when using a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If I have this list comprehension:

```
[list(range(0,x)) for x in [1, 2, 3]]
```

I get

```
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

But I would like to get:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Noticed that the example above is just a minimal example.

I have read a lot of [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) that explain how to flatten a list of lists but I have found nothing on how to avoid the creation of sublist inside the list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nested comprehension à la:

```
[y for x in [1,2,3] for y in range(x)]
# [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Or, if you are into utils and cryptic brevity:

```
from itertools import chain

[*chain(*map(range, [1, 2, 3]))]
# or, as the traditionalists would suggest:
# list(chain.from_iterable(map(range, [1, 2, 3])))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, it was not clear for me that we don't have to respect the "right to left" order in a nested list comprehension.

Comment: Yeah, the scope in a flat nested comprehension can be counter-intuitive at first. But it is exactly the order as you would have collecting the elements in nested loops.